# Connect to server, send request and receive response through one global function in swift

Tags: iphone, json, swift, xcode6, global

I am very much beginner in swift as well as Xcode. I am building an app in which I need to connect the sever on a particular IP and port, send a JSON request to sever and receives its response many places in code. So I want to make a **global function** (which can be accessible from any part of the code.) for this. I also want to **implement a module (like in VB6.0) or a file** which contains all the global functions and can be called where I need it.

***My first question is that can I return the server response from the following function to the calling function while using httpGet function.***

This function connects to the server, sends request to the sever and get the response only when **the '//return abc!;' code is commented.**

```
func connserv(jsonString:NSDictionary) -> NSDictionary{
    var abc: NSDictionary?
    // This is the action performed when clicked on the Connect button on the connectivity screen
    println("------------------Function connserv")

    let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var IP: AnyObject = prefs.objectForKey("IP")!
    var port: AnyObject = prefs.objectForKey("Port")!
    println("IP in Connection : \(IP)")
    println("port in Connection : \(port)")
    prefs.synchronize()
    //var learn = LearnNSURLSession()
    let localizedModel = UIDevice.currentDevice().localizedModel
    let model = UIDevice.currentDevice().model
    let devicesystemVersion = UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion

    println("HTTP request jsonString : \(jsonString)")
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://\(IP):\(port)/")!)

    var response: NSURLResponse?
    var error: NSError?

    //println("HTTP request jsonString : \(jsonString)")

    var err: NSError?
    request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(jsonString, options: nil, error: &err)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    // send the request
    var learn = LearnNSURLSession()
    println("HTTP request : \(request)")
    learn.httpGet(request) {
        (resultString, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil
        {
            println("completion block")

        }
        else
        {
            let data = (resultString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            var er: NSError?
            let JSONdata: AnyObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers,error: &er)!

            let abc: AnyObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves, error:&er)!

            println("abc : \(abc)")
            println("JSONdata : \(JSONdata)")

            learn.callback(result: resultString, error: error)
        }
    }
    //return abc!;
}
```

Once I **uncommented the '//return abc!;' code** this function does not connect to sever and does not send the request to server and gives the following error:

[image]

```
HTTP request : <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7b99abf0> { URL: https://144.1.1.45:9299/ }
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Please let me know how can I correct this function so that the **connserv** function connects to the server, sends request to the sever and returns the server response to the calling function.

Also let me know how can I make this function as global function as well as call this global function globally in the code where I need it.

Answer (score 0):

`httpGet` runs asynchronously. Its completion block does not get executed until after the request completes. That means your `return` call is happening before you've got your object downloaded, so `abc` is still `nil` at that point, despite the fact that you've force-unwrapped it with `!`. You've got to pass `abc` via the `httpGet` completion block (or just handle it inside the block).

this function should already be visible to other source files in your project

Comment: Please let me know should I change this function so that It works?

Comment: Nick, after your reply I searched more on the internet and found the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647406/how-to-use-completionhandler-closure-with-return-in-swift. After going through this link. I have a doubt that can I return the server response to calling function?