# Return String from URLSession Completion Handler function Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsurlsession, completionhandler

I need this function (which is getting some data from a database) to return a string but I'm having trouble figuring out how. I've found some similar questions/solutions but I'm still struggling to implement a proper solution (I'm pretty new with swift)

```
class Helper{
static func pReq(jsonURL : String, col : String) -> String {
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
    let url  = URL(string: jsonURL)!
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    var string = ""

    let downloadTask = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if(error == nil){ 
            print("data = \(String(describing: data))")
            do{
                print(jsonURL)
                let dataDownloadedAsJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]
                print("dataDownloadedAsJson = \(dataDownloadedAsJson)")
                do{

                    if(dataDownloadedAsJson[col] as? String != nil){
                        string = (dataDownloadedAsJson[col] as? String)!

                    }
                }
            }
            catch{
            }
        }
        else{
            print("Error downloading data. Error = \(String(describing: error))")
        }
    })
    downloadTask.resume()
    return string
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Pretty close to a dupe [of this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647406/how-to-use-completionhandler-closure-with-return-in-swift).

Answer (score 4):

Your `session.dataTask(with:` method is asynchronous. This means that it is going to execute "in the background" and with inform you of when it is finished getting a response from it's call. It will inform you of this inside your block below the `session.dataTask(with:` portion inside the "`{}`". As if appears, you are doing some processing with the JSON that you receive and formatting that into the string you'd like to return from this function. **BUT** you are called `return string` at the bottom well before your call is getting completed, so you will return `""` nothing. What you really need to do is not return anything from your function, but instead use a completion block:

1) Declare this atop your file:

```
typealias StringCompletion      = (_ success: Bool, _ string: String) -> Void
```

---

2) Modify your function to take a parameter for your completion

```
// This
static func pReq(jsonURL : String, col : String) -> String

// Becomes This
static func pReq(jsonURL : String, col : String, completion: @escaping StringCompletion)
```

---

3) Inside your function call your completion and pass back a `Bool` to indicate it was a successful call and pass back the `string` as well

```
class Helper{
static func pReq(jsonURL : String, col : String, completion: @escaping StringCompletion) {
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
    let url  = URL(string: jsonURL)!
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    var string = ""

    let downloadTask = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if(error == nil){ 
            print("data = \(String(describing: data))")
            do{
                print(jsonURL)
                let dataDownloadedAsJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]
                print("dataDownloadedAsJson = \(dataDownloadedAsJson)")
                do{

                    if(dataDownloadedAsJson[col] as? String != nil){
                        string = (dataDownloadedAsJson[col] as? String)! 
                        completion(true, string)
                    }
                }
                catch { completion(false, string) }
            }
            catch{
                completion(false, string)
            }
        }
        else{
            print("Error downloading data. Error = \(String(describing: error))")       
            completion(false, string)
        }
    })
    downloadTask.resume()
}
}
```

---

4) Usage:

```
Helper().pReq(jsonURL: jsonURL, col: col) { (success, string) in
    if success {
        print("Success: \(string)")
    }
    else {
        print("Failure: Unable To Get String")
    }
}
```